# SVN how do I check code into a specific branch, when I've checked code out from the trunk?

Tags: svn, commit, checkin

I need to check in my code changes to a certain branch but im not sure how to do that since my code is from trunk =/

Comment: Thanks guys. So how do I use SVN switch? I have IntelliJ and TortoiseSVN on a Windows XP box

Comment: Should I just check out the branch, load my code changes into it, and then check out from there?

Comment: You can do a switch or that.   I edited my Answer to include how to switch with TortoiseSVN.   I personally use switch all the time.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
cd workingcopy
svn checkout http://my.repos.com/path/to/trunk
# make your edits
svn switch http://my.repos.com/path/to/branch
svn commit
```

Now your working copy points to the branch instead of the trunk.  You could also check out the branch as a separate working copy, then drag-and-drop your changes into it.

Comment: the last part im considering since i dont know how switch will impact the repository or my code, and i dont want to break anything...

so i guess it's best practice to figure out which branch my code changes are going to in advance of checking things out.

Comment: `switch` is just like `update`, but with the added ability to let you point to a different location in the repository, like another branch. It won't make any structural changes to your repository — it just changes which part of the repository that working copy is looking at.

Answer (score 4):

Using Switch allows you to change a checkout from one repository location to another, such as Trunk to a branch.

Then you can commit the changes to the branch.

Using TortoiseSVN you can Perform Switch doing the following.

1. Right Click on the Directory in question you want switch.
2. Select TortoiseSVN | Switch
3. Change the Repository Location from the current one to the new location.

The documentation for this can be [found here](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-branchtag.html).

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a working copy of the branch you want to commit to. So check it out in a separate directory, or use `svn switch`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to switching, you can also create a patch.

http://ariejan.net/2007/07/03/how-to-create-and-apply-a-patch-with-subversion/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of the exact situtation, but it might be an idea to merge changes in to the branch.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of the exact situtation, but it might be an idea to merge changes in to the branch

or

You need to have a working copy of the branch you want to commit to. So check it out in a separate directory, or use svn switch.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found a way to do this. Check out the branch, copy code changes, and the recommit from checked out branch =]